# Media player with SurfaceView get audio and black screen on android api level 22 and less

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

I'm trying to play a video using Media player and SurfaceView, on android api level 23 it's working fine but on level 22 and less I get only audio and black screen.

Here is my code: (it's all inside a fragment)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pageInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);

    playButton = (ImageView) pageInflater.findViewById(R.id.playImage);
    videoSurface = (SurfaceView)pageInflater.findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    controller = new VideoControllerView(getActivity());
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) pageInflater.findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));

    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);


    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      public void onClick(View v) {                                    
                     playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                                     
                     playButton.setClickable(false);
                     player.stop();
                     player.reset();
                     setVideo();
                     player.start();
                                      }
                                  }
    );

    return pageInflater;
}
```

Setting the video and starting to play it:

```
private void setVideo() {
    String vidAddress = tutorialsVideo["SOME URL"];
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse(vidAddress));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error while playing video. Please, check your network connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            player.seekTo(currentVideoPosition);
            player.start();

        }
    });

    player.prepareAsync();

    playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    playButton.setClickable(false);

}
```

SurfaceHolder implements:

```
// Implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.release();
}
// End SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

The code is working fine on LG G4 with Android API level 23 and on the Android Studio Emulator Nexus 5 API 23, but when I'm trying to run it on my Samsung S3 API 19 and on any Emulator with API 22 or less I get audio with black screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have u find the solution?